# OpenLayers Icon e PopUp

Tags: openlayers-2, php

Ciao, sto creando una pagina in php con una mappa ... in OpenLayers Examples ho trovato due interessanti esempi:

- esempio che mostra come usare diversi tipi di poupup (http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/popupMatrix.html)
- esempio per inserire icone personalizzate (http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/markers.html)

Il mio problema è che non riesco ad integrare i due esempi...

dal primo:

```
echo" 
        ll = new OpenLayers.LonLat($lng,$lat).transform( 
            new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913') 
        ); 
        popupClass = OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored; 
        popupContentHTML = '$T'; 
        addMarker(ll, popupClass, popupContentHTML, false, true);
```

dal secondo:

```
echo" 
        ll = new OpenLayers.LonLat($lng,$lat).transform( 
            new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913') 
        ); 
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(50,50); 
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h); 
        var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('{$row['enclosure']}',size,offset); 
        markers.addMarker( 
            new OpenLayers.Marker( 
                (ll 
                ),icon 
            ) 
        ); 
";
```

Ho notato che nel primo addMarker richiama una funzione, che sembra simile a markers.addMarker

... sinceramente non so dove mettere ", icon" nel primo o nella funzione che richiama?

EDIT - Translation to English (Tradotto in inglese)

Hello, I am creating a php page with a map ... in OpenLayers Examples I found two interesting examples:

• Example showing how to use different types of poupup (http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/popupMatrix.html)

• example to insert custom icons (http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/markers.html)

My problem is that I can not integrate the two examples ...

the first:

```
echo" 
            ll = new OpenLayers.LonLat($lng,$lat).transform( 
                new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913') 
            ); 
            popupClass = OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored; 
            popupContentHTML = '$T'; 
            addMarker(ll, popupClass, popupContentHTML, false, true);
```

The Second:

```
echo" 
        ll = new OpenLayers.LonLat($lng,$lat).transform( 
            new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913') 
        ); 
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(50,50); 
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h); 
        var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('{$row['enclosure']}',size,offset); 
        markers.addMarker( 
            new OpenLayers.Marker( 
                (ll 
                ),icon 
            ) 
        ); 
";
```

I noticed that in the first addMarker calls a function, which looks similar to markers.addMarker

... I honestly do not know where to put "icon" in the first or in the function calling?

Comment: Posts here are expected to be in English. Can you at least use Google Translate and then other people can try and correct it. Otherwise your audience will be a very small fraction of GIS Stack Exchange

Comment: ho fatto una demo: 
[http://78.134.3.20:81/simple_page/openlayers_001/php/fm_prima.php](http://78.134.3.20:81/simple_page/openlayers_001/php/fm_prima.php)

Ho messo tre icone e nella pagina, ma anche semplicemente facendo view source in Chrome, si può capire... 

Pj